# Get filename from model name in Rails (and vice versa)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to go from a Rails model's filename (e.g. `/app/models/foo/bar.rb`) to its model name (e.g. `Foo::Bar`)? And/or vice-versa?

Or do I have to parse the strings to figure out what they correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From model to filename

["app/models/", Foo::Bar.to_s.underscore, ".rb"].join("")

from filename to model

"app/models/foo/bar.rb".sub("app/models/", "").sub(".rb", "").classify

I know this looks like a hack. But there is no easy way of doing this stuff

Answer (score 0):

It seems the closest thing that can be done is with the `underscore` and `camelize` methods in [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html).